# sql - double condition check in sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, call Table1 and Table2. Table1 columns are id,name,col3.
Table2 has columns id, name , col3.
I want to extract all records from Table1 who's id and name (Both to satisfy condition)
not in Table2.
How to do that

Comment: i tried some thing 
SELECT     dbo.Table1.ID AS id, dbo.Table1.Track_Name AS Name
FROM         dbo.Table1 Not IN (Select Id from Table2 )
Need also to check the name where Name should also be at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the below assist:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.ID, 
    Table1.name, 
    Table1.col3, 
    Table2.ID
FROM 
    Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON (Table2.name = Table1.name) AND (Table2.ID = Table1.ID)
WHERE 
    Table2.ID Is Null;
```

Comment: thank you i worked fine i was not writing the is null in my actual query

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Your query does not even run
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Answer (score 1):

I think you require values( id, name) which are not present in other table.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.name <> t2.name
WHERE t2.id is null
UNION
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
  ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.name <> t2.name
WHERE t1.id is null
```